# User shot - How to display shots from only users you follow (excluding my own)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feed, show

How to display shots from only users you follow (excluding my own)?
I think the problem is in the feed, but I'm very new in Rails, and have no idea how to do it. thanks Devs!

[shot from show page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMGJa.jpg)

```html
[enter image description here][1]

my user.controller

    class User < ApplicationRecord
friendships, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
      has_many :passive_friendships, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy

      has_many :followings, through: :active_friendships, source: :followed
      has_many :followers, through: :passive_friendships, source: :follower

      #follow another user
      def follow(other_user)
        active_friendships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
      end

      #Unfollow a other_user
      def unfollow(other_user)
        active_friendships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
      end
      #Is following a other_user?
      def following?(other_user)
        following_ids.include?(other_user.id)
      end

      def feed
        following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM Friendships WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
        Shot.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
      end

my show.html.erb

      <div class="shots user">
        <% @user.feed.each do|shot|%>
        <section class="section">
          <div class="shot-grid-item">
            <div class="shot-wrapper">
              <%= link_to shot, class: "shot" do %>
              <% if shot.user_shot_url.present? %>
              <%= cl_image_tag(shot.user_shot_url) %>
              <% else %>
              <label><%= shot.description %></label>
              <div class="shot-data">
                <h3 class="shot-title"><%= shot.title %></h3>
                <div class="shot-description"><%= truncate(shot.description, length: 60) %></div>
                <div class="shot-time">
                  <%= time_ago_in_words(shot.created_at) %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <% end %>
              <% end%>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
<%= current_user.followings.shots.each do |shot| %>
<% end %>
```

Better - You can declare in the controller a variable that extracts this logic from the view:

```
@following_shots = current_user.followings.shots
```

Then in the view

```
<%= @following_shots.each do |shot| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: for me is not working, a change the feed to  def feed
    following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM Friendships WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    Shot.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids})", user_id: id)
  end  but is showing number os shot from user, not each user.